# Moving Angularjs project to ReactJS

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, webpack

I have an `AngularJS` project with a `NodeJS` (<6) backend.

The files (including `angular's` libraries) are stored in a `src/js` directory that served from the server from an `HTML` `script` tags.

The app use plain `CSS`.

I want to convert this app to a react app.

I saw that a lot of guides recommend to first move to `Webpack`, and then to `react`
but they are relying on the fact that your app is pre-built like the `angular` pack app, with all the libraries coming from node_modules and pre loaded.

min isn't that way as you see.

What are the best methods to convert the app slowly to React?
I want to use the React with `JSX` and all the new stuff.

Will it be easier to rebuild the app from scratch, or to migrate slowly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the needs of the project.  Is this a personal project where you're the only stakeholder?  Then i'd say just rewrite from scratch.  If this is an app for a company you work for, migrating slowly could be the best option.  The React app can basically be a "separate" app, separated by a route, or you could even use React components inside an angular component with ngReact.  The benefit is that you can build the React app separately, and just pull it into your current Angular build.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i have did